# Python Server/Client

Tags: python, sql, sockets, pickle

I am trying to do a Vending Machine program in python.
In the client side, I have the GUI and the transaction, payment etc..
On the server side, I have linked the file to a SQL which contain the quantity of products etc..

I did manage to make some modification when a customer buy a product.
What i don't know how to do, is how can I tell to my server :
"Each time you receive a transaction, check and update my DB"
Can you guide me how to do this? Or can I do it another way?

To send and receive Data I use the socket module and use pickle as I send a list of list.
I Have 9 product and each contain a ID , name , price and a quantity which i must update:
ex:

```
#recieve
    updatestock = socket_client.recv(1024)
    updatestock2 = pickle.loads(updatestock)
#send
    server_message = pickle.dumps(stocklist)
    socket_client.sendall(server_message)

#What i send
stocklist = [
['P001','ChocolateBar',35,15],
['...','...',..,..],
[etc]].
```

I hope you can help me without seeing all my code as it is really long.Thank you!

This is my attemp:

```
while(True):
    if socket_client.recv(1024):
        updatestock = socket_client.recv(1024)
        updatestock2 = pickle.loads(updatestock)
        print(updatestock2)
        if updatestock2 == "Quit":
            break
        else:
             update()
mydb.close()
socket_client.close()
```

As you can see printing the received message updatestock2 doesn't give me anything so i think here is the problem

Comment: in the receive transaction part of the code, you check and update the DB? What's wrong with that idea?

Comment: well the idea is good , but i don't know how to make a kind of While infinite loop updating the Db each time i have a query

Comment: you don't know how to make an infinite while loop?

Comment: I do but I can't find out how to read the data when something is send from the client. I updated my question check for my attemp please.

Comment: did you consider that the first call to recv(1024) receives the message and then the second call to recv(1024) waits for another message?

Comment: if , for exemple putting the client message into a variable and doing something like this should work? 
if updatestock2 != 0:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to do an infinite loop recognising client message like this:

```
while(True):
    updatestock = socket_client.recv(1024)  #wait for message
    updatestock2 = pickle.loads(updatestock)
    if updatestock2 != 0:     #if message is not empty do these condition
        if updatestock2 == "Quit":  
            break
        elif updatestock2 == "Graph":
            graph(stocklist,stock_status)
        else:
             update()     #this update my Db
```